# Python Multithreading program killed by the OS

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I was curious on how the python implement multithread  and how GIL affects the performance. I just started to test some simple python script performance on a virtualbox ubuntu 15.04 guest. But I met a problem: the multithread script just was killed after it was executed for a small duration.

**EDIT**
I found the problem is on:

```
for _ in range(200000000):
```

if I change the range(python 2.7) to xrange, then it will be fine.
I know this is because range return a list and xrange just return an iterator.
But I still wonder to know what the range() limit is.

**My testing environment:**

NAME="Ubuntu"

VERSION="15.04 (Vivid Vervet)"

2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Linux 3.19.0-15-generic (simon-VirtualBox)  12/06/2016  _x86_64_    (1 CPU)

**The script**

```
 #! /usr/bin/python

from threading import Thread
import time

def my_counter():
    i = 0
    for _ in range(100000000):
        i = i + 1
    return True

def main():
    thread_array = {}
    start_time = time.time()
    for tid in range(2):
        t = Thread(target=my_counter)
        t.start()
        thread_array[tid] = t
    for i in range(2):
        thread_array[i].join()
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Total time: {}".format(end_time - start_time))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**The Output**

```
simon@simon-VirtualBox:~/Dropbox/python/GIL$ time py multiThread.py 
Killed

real    0m6.712s
user    0m2.832s
sys 0m3.056s
```

**Question**

Is this issue related to the single cpu or I just misunderstood something?

Comment: because that's the "duration" it took the run the tasks given to it

Comment: I don't see the `Killed` it runs fine for me but Im not in VM and am on 16.04. Are you using python 2? If so perhaps the `range(100000000)` used too much memory? Try reducing the range by a few orders of magnitude and see if it starts behaving.

Comment: My bad,  the counter in the for loop range should be 200000000.
This large number will make the range() function fail for the overflow.
But now I want to figure out what the limit is.